# Homepage incorrect in Symfony2 (installation)

Tags: php, apache, symfony

When Symfony2 has completed the installation process, I went to `http://localhost:8000` and the result is a blank page with the text "Homepage. " and the Symfony developer bar at the bottom.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't see what's the problem? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: Normally, this is the home of Symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/_images/welcome.png, but I don't understand why they don't appear that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you only get the fancy "installed" homepage if you install the demo bundle.